# How do you edit styles to make headings have a page-width horizontal rule?

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I want my headings to be underlined and have the line span the full width of the page, but I can't just _________ underscore across the page because the underscores appear in my table of contents. How can I modify my header style to just make the line go the full width of the page?

Comment: Are you looking for full page width (edge to edge of the paper), or the width of the margins (content width)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying a lower edge border to the Paragraph in the Style editor?
[image]